# Convert String to a float (which will cover different variation of value)

Tags: python

I have searched, but could not find anything which will help (may be it does not exist)

What I'm looking for, is a way to convert STRING to a VALUE, which will auto handle different variations.

E.G.

- FROM: `"111,111.56"` TO `111111.56`
- FROM `123.34.45` TO `12334.45`
- FROM `123.34,45` TO `12334.45`
- Can have multiple separators

  - `1.2.3.34,45`, `1,2,3.34,45`, `1,2.3.34,45`, `1.2,3.34,45`

In this example really all that need to be done is to remove any `,` or `.` and keep the last one (if the last one is `,`, then replace it with `.` and that it)

- FROM: `1.2.3.34,45`

  - TO: `12334,45`
  - TO: `12334.45`
- FROM: `1.2.3.34.45`

  - TO: `12334.45`

I know that it can be solved by a simple `.replace()` function, but I just thought maybe it is no need to reinvent a wheel and something much clever already exists.

If it is not possible and the only way is to use `.replace()` function... sad... but all good :) this is more about... try to use the best practices...

Potential idea:

```
x= "1.2,3.34,45"
xl = list(x)
a = "".join(["".join([i for i in xl[0:-3] if i not in [".",","]]),"".join(xl[-3:]).replace(",",".")]) if xl[-3] in [".",","] else "".join(xl)
print(a)
```

Comment: Storing float value in different ways is not the best thing IMO. How is `123.34.45` a float value?

Comment: @sashaaero they coming in these different ways..... not all source of data are clean

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.atof

Comment: @sashaaero the point of the question is to convert these odd/strange format values to a float one. I can use simply `.replace()` but I have a feeling of reinventing the wheel... and thought that might be something more clever already exists

Comment: @SaatvikRamani will not handle any of the examples :) I know you can change the locale, but data is not because of location... the simple answer is because it is not great ... :)

Comment: @OksanaOk you need to set a locale before using `atof`.

Comment: @SaatvikRamani sorry have just amended my answer above.... the data coming this way, not because of localisation, but because it is not great....

Comment: I guess `reinvent a wheel` only goes with solving common problems. I don't think this is the case. So IMO replace is okay.

Comment: WHat is the point of putting minus to this question... without any explanations.... this is so strange ... Question IS valid ... as it will be greater to have something which will handle this....

Comment: "E.G." Please list all formats that you expects. There's no point in us *guessing* what formats you need handled.

Comment: What is the rule that tells you that `"123.34.45"` should become `12334.45`? Why should it not become `12.33445` instead?

Comment: We read your question. It doesn't make sense as asked. "Something generic... that will do what I need" is *not a specific enough description of a problem to be able to write code to solve it*.

Comment: Didn't downvote your question, but why there would be generic solution for absolutely non-proper number format? :) Custom format - custom solution.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel By analysing sample data, I saw the pattern..  that it will normally have 2 numbers at the end and then it will break because of `,` or `.` is somewhere in the middle multiple times... (if it will break else how... then it needs to be refined )

Comment: @KarlKnechtel @ sinisake , a generic function that will solve it by adding few settings to tune it up.... I think it DOES exist as it is common problem when you working with unstructured data.... and MANY people facing this problem! So the assumption is that if this is a common problem someone may be done something around it...!

Comment: That is still *nowhere near* an answerable Stack Overflow question (and if you are looking for an existing library, that is *explicitly* off-topic). Please read [ask].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe it is worth do delete this question as it is my fault to ask this here... tbh I thought it will be a great one... and it will not end up like this... as in my head it is like a puzzle...is it possible to generalise this or not...

Comment: If you do have an existing format in mind, such as "last separator is decimal separator", *that's completely fine and answerable*. If you don't and just list some examples that are explicitly not complete, that is not answerable. There's no need to burn the question down, but there is need to clearly define what it is about.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi have amended this question ......

Comment: @OksanaOk, what is your code/idea for this? In any case, you just need few lines of code, as you know, including function definition :), to cover all listed cases. Challenge could be to make some kind of code golfing. :)

Comment: Yes, i have used something  little simpler: def floater(s):
    import re
    r = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', s)
    return float(r[0:-2]+'.'+r[-2:])

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way to achieve what you are looking for.

However this function will do the job:

```
>>> def convert(value):
...     comma = ","
...     dot = "."
...     last_comma_index = value.rfind(comma)
...     last_dot_index = value.rfind(dot)
...     if last_comma_index > last_dot_index:
...         last_index = last_comma_index
...     else:
...         last_index = last_dot_index
...     before_point = value[:last_index]
...     no_commas = "".join(before_point.split(comma))
...     no_dots = "".join(no_commas.split(dot))
...     return no_dots + dot + value[last_index + 1:]
... 
>>> convert("1.2.3.34,45")
'12334.45'
>>> convert("1.2,3.34,45")
'12334.45'
>>> convert("1,2.3.34,45")
'12334.45'
>>> convert("1,2,3.34,45")
'12334.45'
```